Sort on results of pivot table
Simple table
Simple table with coordinator name name (column A), completed date (column B) and customer's name (column C). I need to find the response rate for each coordinator (response rate = count completed date (exclude null) divide by total count of customers assigned to each coordinator). The results should then be sorted by the response rate.
Sample Table
Response Table
I've tried adding a formula to Sample Table that replaced Completed with 1 if it is not blank and then use a pivot table to count Customers and sum on formula (aka # responded). I can then create a pivot table calculated field (field1) that does the division to get the response rate. What I can't do is sort it on field1 (calculated field) so that those with the greatest response rate are listed 1st. I've tried, on the pivot table, to click off as well as on Use Custom Lists when sorting, no luck. Please note I have to share this with an outside vendor who will be copying and pasting in new data each day and then will need to update the results. Thanks!
